# Why isn't super() working correctly in HourlyEmployee class?

Tags: java, super

I'm trying to write a simple payroll system program. I'm having problems with `super(employee_1);` in the `HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1)` method. The reason I'm getting is "actual and formal arguments differ in length. However, when I change the arguments to include everything, I get an error in my `main class(payrollSystem_1)` in the line `HourlyEmployee employee_2 = new HourlyEmployee(employee_1);` it says that the method should only say `HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1)`.

I'm just stuck and can't fix the `super(employee_1)`.

PayrollSystem_1.java

```
package payrollsystem_1;
import java.util.*;

public class PayrollSystem_1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here



        // Creating an HourlyEmployee object using the first constructor
        HourlyEmployee employee_1 = new HourlyEmployee(1, "Janette", "Hernandez", null, 14.75, 30);

        // Creating an HourlyEmployee object using the copy constructor
        HourlyEmployee employee_2 = new HourlyEmployee(employee_1);


        // Calling some of the setter methods in the HourlyEmployee class.
        employee_2.setEmployeeID(2);
        employee_2.setFirstName("Marcela");
        employee_2.setLastName("Brown");
        employee_2.setHourlyRate(25);
        employee_2.setPeriodHours(40);

        System.out.println("\nCalling some of the getter methods in the HourlyEmployee class...");
        System.out.println( String.format("%-30s%s", "Employee ID:", employee_1.getEmployeeID()) );
        System.out.println( String.format("%-30s%s", "First Name:", employee_1.getFirstName()) );
        System.out.println( String.format("%-30s%s", "Last Name:", employee_1.getLastName()) );
        System.out.println( String.format("%-30s%s", "Hourly Rate:", employee_1.getHourlyRate()) );
        System.out.println( String.format("%-30s%s", "Period Hours:", employee_1.getPeriodHours()) );
```

HourlyEmployee.java

```
        public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {

            private double hourlyRate;

            private double periodHours;



            /**

    * @param employeeID

    * @param firstName

    * @param lastName

    * @param listOfPaychecks

    * @param hourlyRate

    * @param periodHours

    * Constructor with parameters

    */

            public HourlyEmployee( int employeeID, String firstName, String lastName, ArrayList<Paycheck> listOfPaychecks,

            double hourlyRate, double periodHours) {

                super(employeeID, firstName, lastName, listOfPaychecks);

                this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;   

                this.periodHours = periodHours;

            }

            /**
    * @param employee_1
    * 

    * 

    */

            public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1) {

                super(employee_1);

                this.hourlyRate = employee_1.hourlyRate;

                this.periodHours = employee_1.periodHours;

            }

            /**

    * @return hourlyRate

    */

            public double getHourlyRate() {

                return hourlyRate;

            }

            /**

    * @param hourlyRate

    */

            public void setHourlyRate(double hourlyRate) {

                this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;

            }

            /**

    * @return periodHours

    */

            public double getPeriodHours() {

                return periodHours;

            }

            /**

    * @param periodHours

    */

            public void setPeriodHours(double periodHours) {

                this.periodHours = periodHours;

            }

        }
```

Employee.java

```
        public abstract class Employee {
            int employeeID;
            String firstName;
            String lastName;
            ArrayList<Paycheck>listOfPaychecks;
            double hourlyRate;
            double periodHours;

            /**

    * @param employeeID

    * @param firstName

    * @param lastName

    * @param listOfPaychecks

    * Parameterized Constructor

    */

            public Employee (int employeeID, String firstName, String lastName, 
            ArrayList<Paycheck> listOfPaychecks){
                this.employeeID = employeeID;
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.listOfPaychecks = listOfPaychecks;

            }

            public int getEmployeeID() {
                return employeeID;
            }

            public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID){
                this.employeeID = employeeID;        
            }

            public String getFirstName(){
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName){
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getLastName(){
                return lastName;
            }

            public void setLastName(String lastName){
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

            public ArrayList<Paycheck> getListOfPaychecks(){
                return listOfPaychecks;
            }

            public void setListOfPaychecks(ArrayList<Paycheck> listOfPaychecks){
                this.listOfPaychecks = listOfPaychecks;
            }
            @Override

            public String toString() {

                StringBuffer employeeInfo=new StringBuffer();

                employeeInfo.append("Employee ID: "+employeeID+" First Name: "+firstName+" Last Name: "+lastName+"\nPay Check Details: \n");

                for (Paycheck paycheck : listOfPaychecks) {

                    employeeInfo.append(paycheck.toString());
                }

                return employeeInfo.toString();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. We want to help, but there's way too much code here, most of which is irrelevant to the problem. Hint: which constructor are you expecting your `super(employee_1)` call to chain to? I don't see any applicable constructor in `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your constructor when you call super - super has no such constructor

```
        public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1) {
            super(employee_1);
            this.hourlyRate = employee_1.hourlyRate;
            this.periodHours = employee_1.periodHours;
        }
```

Change your constructor like this:

```
    public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1) {
        super(employee_1.employeeID, employee_1.firstName, employee_1.lastName, employee_1.listOfPaychecks);
        this.hourlyRate = employee_1.hourlyRate;
        this.periodHours = employee_1.periodHours;
    }
```

Or better still like this:

```
    public HourlyEmployee(HourlyEmployee employee_1) {
        this (employee_1.employeeID, employee_1.firstName, employee_1.lastName, employee_1.listOfPaychecks, employee_1.hourlyRate, employee_1.periodHours);
    }
```